# SQLAlchemy filter_by json column

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have model like this:

```
class Customer(Base):
__tablename__ = 'customers'
uuid = database.Column(database.String, primary_key=True)
activity_type = database.Column(database.String)
activity = database.Column(database.JSON)
```

I need to filter_by activity_type and also activity like this:

```
@staticmethod
def create_if_not_exist(customer):
    """ Create customer if not exists """
    if Customer.query.filter_by(
            activity_type=customer.activity_type,
            activity=customer.activity
    ).first() is None:
        customer.save()

    return customer.uuid
```

If doesnt work for json colum activity. Can someone help me how to filter_by json column ?

Comment: What database system is this intended for? MySQL? SQLite? PostgreSQL?

Comment: I think this should work fine for SQLite.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

One PostgreSQL specific solution to this is to utilize PostgreSQLs JSONB column:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB

class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'
    uuid = database.Column(database.String, primary_key=True)
    activity_type = database.Column(database.String)
    activity = database.Column(JSONB)
```

Your original query should then evaluate properly.

Comment: I think if you **must** use JSON then you'll probably have to do some sort of casting to text and then compare it. If your criteria are to only match certain keys in the JSON then you could possibly match the keys specifically with JSON as well. For equality operation I think JSONB is a shortcut as well as being more efficient in a lot of ways.